# Django ImproperlyConfigured for import User

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

I am trying to customize django registration form. And my forms.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True,label='First Name')
    last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True,label='Last Name')
    email=forms.EmailField(label='Email Address')
    company_or_institution=forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True,label='Company or Institution Name')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self,commit = True):   
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.company_or_institution = self.cleaned_data['company_or_institution']

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

And my views.py is

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print form.is_valid()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', args)
```

But when I am testing my forms.py from terminal (python forms.py) I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "forms.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib /auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
from django.core.cache import caches
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Anyone has any idea how to fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your forms, or indeed any of your code.

If you are going to be using Django at all, you should start your terminal using `python manage.py shell`, so that it sets up the environment properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I didn't get your answer can you please explain in more details

Comment: Translation: Don't run `python forms.py`. Instead, run `python manage.py shell` and import your form classes from that shell. Using the `shell` command will set up the environment (and pull in Django settings) so that you can interact with models, forms, views, etc.